# How to identify which types can be generified?

Tags: java, generics

I know that object based collections are prime candidates for generification  and have already been generified in the collections library .  Other than that what attributes and behaviors  should a class or interface  possess so as to make it a candidate for generification ? Why for example the  `ThreadLocal` class or the `AtomicReference` class were generified ? What led to this design decision ?

Comment: Basically, any class that accepts and returns objects of another class where that second class is likely to be subclassed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a class can have the same relationship with a variety of other classes, then that class is a good candidate for generification.  Collections classes are generified because the relationship, "contains", can apply to any class of object.  The `Comparable` and `Comparator` interfaces are generic because the relationship "can compare to" can apply to many different objects (although in practice this is limited to objects in and around the class's own hierarchy for `Comparable`).

Additionally, if you find yourself writing multiple classes that are very similar, where the only difference is the type of the objects with which you're operating, then consider writing one generified class.

**EDIT:**

With the built-in classes `AtomicReference` and `ThreadLocal`, the "contains" relationship applies to a variety of object types.  An `AtomicReference` and a `ThreadLocal` object still contain an object of another type.  This allows that specific type to be set and returned in a type-safe way, without the need to have the "get" and "set" methods return/take an `Object` and it eliminates the need to cast the return type when calling the "get" method.  The relationship applies to a *particular type*, but the exact type doesn't need to be known at class design time.

**EDIT 2:**

Most examples I can think of for making a class generic involve the "contains" relationship.  However, that is just one specific example of a generic relationship, even though the Collections framework is based on the "contains" relationship, and it provides lots of "contains"-generified classes.  A generic relationship doesn't have to be "contains", so I'll try to give an example of where something can be generified but the relationship is "contains".

Imagine an abstract `Shape` class, with concrete classes such as `Line`, `Square`, `Circle`, etc.  Now we define the interface `ShapeDrawer` that knows how to draw shapes.  The relationship here is "draws".  We could define the interface:

```
public interface ShapeDrawer {
   public void drawShape(Shape shape);
}
```

Now we need specific concrete implementations of `ShapeDrawer` that specialize in specific shapes, e.g. `CircleDrawer` and `SquareDrawer`.

```
public class CircleDrawer implements ShapeDrawer {
   public void drawShape(Shape shape) {/*...*/}
}
```

Now the `drawShape` method in `CircleDrawer` must test its `shape` to see if it's a `Circle` before drawing it.

Now, a solution with generics:

```
public interface ShapeDrawer<T extends Shape> {
   public void drawShape(T shape);
}
```

Now, an implementation can draw a specific `Shape`:

```
public class CircleDrawer implements ShapeDrawer<Circle> {
    public void drawShape(Circle circle) {/*...*/}
}
```

Comment: @regrettman so the specific class type has to be some some kind of object holder/container  ?

Answer (score 3):

The class that needs to be reused for different types always is a candidate for a generification.
For example `class Pair<U,V>`

Answer (score 1):

Data structures should be generic, because the structure should be able to deal with more than one type of input.

Any class that could/should be used by more than one data type should be created in a generic way.

Answer (score 1):

Do not look for things to "generify". Rather you should use generics to accomplish a specific task in the way you see fit best. Generics is just a tool in your toolbox to accomplish your tasks.

If your question is what kind of things are probably best implemented generically then your own example is a prime one. Generics are a good solution when you need to handle different structures in a similar manner, like lists. This include most classes that deal with other classes in a class-invariant manner, or are invariant over a subsection of classes.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you find yourself casting a value, you should consider whether generification would let you remove that cast. Let's take your examples, `ThreadLocal` and `AtomicReference`. Both times using the value returned by `get()` would require a cast (at least most of the time).

Keep in mind that generics can be quite noisy. Weigh the costs and benefits. In particular, consider whether generification benefits API users or just just you, the implementor.